# How do I pass libsass configuration variables into a flask_assets bundle?

Tags: python, flask, libsass, flask-assets, webassets

My goal is to set `LIBSASS_STYLE="expanded"` via `flask_assets.Bundle`. The [webassets libsass documentation](http://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_filters.html#webassets.filter.libsass.LibSass) says I can do it, but doesn't say how.

My base app controller looks like the following.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle

app = Flask(__name__)

# ... Typical flask controller stuff

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    assets = Environment(app)

    css = Bundle(
        'sass/*.scss',         # input scss files
        filters='libsass',     # to be compiled by libsass
        output='css/style.css' # and outputed to style.css
    )

    assets.register("asset_css", css)

    app.run(debug=True)
```

This outputs a valid css file (which is great) but not in the format that I desire since I simply have no idea where I can slip any libsass options.

Any help on this issue is greatly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate libsass filter explicitly to pass options to it

```
from flask_assets import Bundle
from webassets.filter import get_filter

libsass = get_filter(
    'libsass',
    as_output=True,
    style='compressed',
)

css = Bundle(
    'sass/*.scss',
    filters=(libsass),
    output='css/style.css'
)
```